# How to show if an update installed on windows 7 from WSUS Server?

Tags: wsus, wsus-offline

How to identify if an update installed on windows 7 from WSUS Server? I want to understand this from client side but not server side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following in the command line of Win 7 PC:

```
wuauclt /detectnow
```

Then analyse the *%windir%\WindowsUpdate.log* file on the Windows Update client.

With default settings, this should be:

*C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log*

This log contains attempts of finding, dowlnloading and installing updates.

Section WSUS displays the Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) server that is available to the client. You should get something like this:

```
2018-10-16  08:13:05:414    1088    474 Agent     * WSUS server: http://SERVER_NAME
2018-10-16  08:13:05:414    1088    474 Agent     * WSUS status server: http://SERVER_NAME
```

If you see *NULL* instead of *SERVER_NAME*, then WSUS server is not being used.